# Technique to display delete indicator at SECTION not ROW level

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios7

I have an application with items that have a fixed number of attributes, like a record. I display each item within its own section in a UITableView: the item name is the section header and the attributes are rows:

```
========
Section Header 0: Car A
========
Row 0 - Size: X
Row 1 - Color Y
Row 2 - Number of wheels Z
...
========
Section Header 1: Car B
========
Row 0 - SizeL XX
Row 1 - Color YY
Row 2 - Number of wheels Z
...
```

I want the user to be able to delete items at the section level, like deleting a record. The best way from UI standpoint I can think to do this is to simulate the row-level delete symbol and behavior by moving all the rows within a section to the right and showing the delete symbol centered vertically within the section on the left:

```
=======
Section Header 1
=======
    Row 0
(-) Row 1
    Row 2
```

Is there an accepted way to approach this? Apple is doing this in the Contacts app in iOS7 for the address fields like this:

[image]

What is the general technique for this? Any help or direction greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the address "section" is really one row with several text fields. There is no standard way to have a section-level delete button.

Comment: After spending much too much time on this I think the best solution might be just to make a UITableViewCell that looks like it's a section. In the Apple example treat the whole address as one row.

Answer (score 0):

For others that have looked at this problem, the way to go is to implement rows that looks like sections. In the example of a record that has fields, a row should correspond to a full records, rather than a section for each record with rows within the section for the attributes.

I hope this helps. The Apple example for contacts app is informative here.